# xcode 11.4 code sign failed a nonzero digit while compiling

Tags: xcode, codesign

i faced this issue in onesignal profile while compiling debug ion simulator works perfectly fine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU2oO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try logging out and then back into your Apple Developer account within Xcode.

I suspect what you're seeing has to do with the fact Apple [has recently changed their intermediate Apple Worldwide Developer Relations certificate](https://developer.apple.com/support/wwdr-intermediate-certificate/)?

Comment: Thank you so much i have installed new code 11.7 and installed new mac  it solved my all of problems I was unawre of apple new update.